# Spring GroovyDynamicElementReader tries to read a Groovy script as XML and fails

Tags: rest, groovy, spring-boot, component-scan

When I looked at Spring Boot, I liked the idea that it:

> Gets out of the way quickly if you want to change defaults. - *Dave Syer, Spring One 2GX 2013*

It wasn't long before practicality hit me. While trying to make Boot work with a 100% Groovy/no-XML pet project, I found 2 issues in 2 days. Here's one of them.

Groovy config file:

```
beans {
  xmlns([ctx:'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context'])
  ctx.'component-scan'('base-package':'name.abhijitsarkar.moviedatabase')
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read XML document; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unable to determine validation mode for [Groovy]: cannot open InputStream. Did you attempt to load directly from a SAX InputSource without specifying the validationMode on your XmlBeanDefinitionReader instance?; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Groovy cannot be opened because it does not point to a readable resource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.readDocumentFromString(XmlReaderContext.java:98)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext$readDocumentFromString.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.groovy.GroovyDynamicElementReader.invokeMethod(GroovyDynamicElementReader.groovy:96)
```

Also posted on Spring forum.

Comment: Hard to see what that has to do with Spring Boot, but maybe if you can share some more of the code it might be easier to tell. Could you push a project to github?

Comment: I came to understand that this is not directly related to Boot. I opened a JIRA [SPR-11627](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11627). My full project is [here](https://github.com/abhijitsarkar/groovy/tree/master/movie-database). The test in question is [here](https://github.com/abhijitsarkar/groovy/blob/master/movie-database/movie-database-client/src/test/groovy/name/abhijitsarkar/moviedatabase/client/MovieDatabaseRESTClientIntegrationTest.groovy) though, because of this bug, I've now removed the component-scan from Groovy config and put it on the Application class using @ComponentScan.